# place 2 radio buttons next to each other (on one 'line') in a vertical layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have my controls in a vertical LinearLayout.
All my controls are place below each other.

What i want to do is place a radio group (with 2 radio buttons) on one 'line'

How can i do that?

I tried wrapping it in a horizontal LinearLayout, but that didn't work out

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `android:orientation="horizontal"`-attribute of the RadioGroup.

Comment: wow. Sometimes life can be so easy yet unseen by some devs, like me this time :-)

Comment: How if i want my radio button to fill the next line when the width already full?

Answer (score 3):

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="No Return"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Return"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```